# jQuery Selectors with Variable Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this small piece of jQuery that essentially works to filter content. When a user clicks a button (in this case, an LI element), a specific piece of content "toggles" in visibility.

```
$( "li:contains('Blog')" ).click(function() { // If a user clicks the "Blog" button
  $( ".Blog" ).toggle('slow') // Hide/Show all blog entries
});
```

This works great, but not all entries are going to be blogs - it is completely dynamic. So I need something along the lines of:

```
$( "li:contains('XYZ')" ).click(function() { // If a user clicks this button
  $( ".XYZ" ).toggle('slow') // Hide/Show all entries belonging to that button
});
```

Essentially, if there a better way of writing this:

```
$( "li:contains('Blog')" ).click(function() {
  $( ".Blog" ).toggle('slow')
  $(this).toggleClass( "secondary" )
});

$( "li:contains('Twitter')" ).click(function() {
  $( ".Twitter" ).toggle('slow')
  $(this).toggleClass( "secondary" )
});

$( "li:contains('Facebpok')" ).click(function() {
  $( ".Facebook" ).toggle('slow')
  $(this).toggleClass( "secondary" )
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="button-group filter-button-group">
    <li class="button tiny">Blog </li>
    <li class="button tiny">Twitter </li>
    <li class="button tiny">Facebook </li>
</ul>
```

Current CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPZaNN

Comment: can you share a html sample of the content(element to be toggled) and `li` triggering it

Comment: Added HTML to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example:

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {
          var elem=$(this);
          var txt=elem.html();
          $( "."+txt).toggle('slow');
          $(this).toggleClass( "secondary" )
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your case your content of the li and te class name are the same so

```
<ul class="button-group filter-button-group myfilter">
    <li class="button tiny">Blog</li>
    <li class="button tiny">Twitter</li>
    <li class="button tiny">Facebook</li>
</ul>
```

then have a single handler

```
$(".myfilter li").click(function () {
    $("." + $(this).text().trim()).toggle('slow')
    $(this).toggleClass("secondary")
});
```

---

Even better use a data-* attribute to specify the class anme

```
<ul class="button-group filter-button-group myfilter">
    <li class="button tiny" data-class="Blog">Blog</li>
    <li class="button tiny" data-class="Twitter">Twitter</li>
    <li class="button tiny" data-class="Facebook">Facebook</li>
</ul>
```

then

```
$(".myfilter li").click(function () {
    $("." + $(this).data('class')).toggle('slow')
    $(this).toggleClass("secondary")
});
```

Comment: I threw this into a CodePen, for some reason, its not working. 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJvZRp

Comment: @JeremyE http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hfm02205/ - Added a class `myfilter` to the `ul`

Comment: @JeremyE but would recommend using the `data-*` attribute - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hfm02205/2/

Comment: @JeremyE targetting all the `li` elements within a page can cause unintended results... so you should use specific element selectors